# Are any hunt sabotage groups active in the Nordic countries?

Tags: direct-action, finland, hunting, sweden

[Hunt sabotage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_sabotage), as defined by Wikipedia, is *the direct action that animal rights or animal welfare activists undertake to interfere with hunting activity.*.

One example is the Dutch group Groenfront, which has recently done [various interventionist actions](https://ssl.direkte-aktie.net/cms/groenfront.php?catid=12&subcatid=60) to sabotage hunting. Wikipedia documents the [Hunt Saboteurs Association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_Saboteurs_Association), supposedly worldwide but does not appear to be active outside the [UK](http://hsa.enviroweb.org/index.php), Ireland, and the [United States](http://www.facebook.com/pages/American-Hunt-Saboteurs-Association/199764820061162), if they're active even there.

Hunting, particularly predator hunting, has been a hotly debated topic in the Nordic countries, with radical statements being made on both sides. Considering this background, I wonder: are there any notable recent incidents of hunt sabotage in the Nordic countries, or groups propagating to carry out such?

Answer (score 2):

I have heard a bit about it regarding the hunt of wolf in Sweden. For instance hunters have been photographed.[Aktivister fotograferade vargjägare i licensjakten](https://nwt.se/hagfors/2018/01/04/aktivister-fotograferade)  The most common way seems to be to simply walking around in the forest making a lot of noise to scare away the wolves. Naturally the hunters don't like that very much and there have been reports of activists getting beaten up, threatened and having their cars sabotaged and having their phones stolen.[DN](https://www.dn.se/nyheter/jagare-polisanmald-ska-ha-tagit-strypgrepp-pa-17-arig-aktivist/)[SVT](https://www.svt.se/nyheter/lokalt/vastmanland/brak-under-vargjakten)

Answer (score 1):

> "2010-05-16: Anonymous report: In an action for forest wildlife, four
>   hunting towers in the forests of Scania were knocked over. The towers
>   were then completely destroyed. Two of the towers were large,
>   elaborate structures that took a while to topple but they did fall and
>   they will be expensive to replace. These actions will continue as long
>   as sadists are hunting in our forests. Leave the animals in peace!
>   /Operation Viltvård [wildlife management]"

http://www.djurensbefrielsefront.com/